# Error with Watson Discovery API's add_document method

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I tried to use discovery API with this code but I have a strange error. It seems discovery doesn't recognize my simple HTML and rejects it. I tried with a lot of simple HTML files, but it doesn't work:

```
import sys
import os
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1
```

```
discovery = DiscoveryV1(version="2018-10-15", url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api', username=username, password=password)



with open((os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'html_simple_file.html')), "r") as fileinfo:
    add_doc = discovery.add_document(Environment_Id,
                                     Collection_Id,
                                     file_info=fileinfo,
                                    file_content_type = "text/html")
print(json.dumps(add_doc, indent=2))
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WatsonApiException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
         13                                      Collection_Id,
         14                                      file_info=fileinfo,
    ---> 15                                     file_content_type = "text/html")
         16 print(json.dumps(add_doc, indent=2))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/discovery_v1.py in add_document(self, environment_id, collection_id, file, metadata, file_content_type, filename, **kwargs)
   1246             params=params,
   1247             files=form_data,
-> 1248             accept_json=True)
   1249         return response
   1250 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py in request(self, method, url, accept_json, headers, params, json, data, files, **kwargs)
    488             error_info = self._get_error_info(response)
    489             raise WatsonApiException(response.status_code, error_message,
--> 490                                      info=error_info, httpResponse=response)

WatsonApiException: Error: Invalid Content-Type. Expected 'multipart/form-data', got 'application/octet-stream', Code: 400 , X-dp-watson-tran-id: gateway01-30825332 , X-global-transaction-id: 7ecac92c5bf2f40901d65b74

I don't understand how it works. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the **open** call where you need to pass the file path of the filename(.html). Here's the working code

```
import os
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

discovery = DiscoveryV1(
    version="2018-10-15",
    username='{USERNAME}',
    password='{PASSWORD}',
    #iam_apikey='{apikey}',
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api'
)

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/Users/VMac/Downloads/', 'Ana.json.html')) as fileinfo:
    add_doc = discovery.add_document('{DISCOVERY_ENVIRONMENT_ID}', '{DISCOVERY_COLLECTION_ID}', file=fileinfo).get_result()
print(json.dumps(add_doc, indent=2))
```

Once you pass all the required details in the code above, here's the output

```
{
  "document_id": "6439d5f2-f273-4173-8d25-54dc934df",
  "status": "processing"
}
```

Refer the API document for [add_document here](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/discovery?language=python#add-a-document)